# Is it on topic to ask about installing a game on Wine?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to install [8ballclub](http://www.8ballclub.com/) on Wine and I think there's a [bug](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=9324). Can I ask how to install the game here or will it be close as off topic or low  quality or too specific? or something? Is it okay to ask it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have already checked the Wine appdb site for this app and a how to install and have also read the guide [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine) on how to install apps and still have not been able to install then you might first try reporting the app to the wine developers for further help. If there is a bug with the app then it is not related to Ubuntu but to Wine. Also, as it looks the App has Bronze stat in the Wine APP DB so it might mean the app will not work.

But since Ubuntu is cool and all, if you follow the guide provided you should get the following:

[image]

And after registering I got this:

[image]

Don't ask me how to play I don't even know what in the world i'm looking at but at least the game works, again, following the guide provided.

Training Area (and me sucking at pool)

[image]

Comment: well... it doesn't work, if you press on `practice and playback`  and then on `training` on your left hand, down there, and wait few minutes.. boom error

Comment: Working for me. btw what is the `` you are referring to? Also if you want to continue you will need to provide the Wine version and Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: I updated my comment, please try that :) i hit enter by mistake and my comment wasn't published correctly

Comment: I have updated the answer to include an image. Please post Wine and Ubuntu version (And even what video card you have). This is very important and can help us solve your problem.

Comment: see those triangles there? the cones? the brown stuff? they shouldn't be there and soon it will tell you failed to initialize 3d components, stuff like that :) error #2000 - I can tell you're using the default xorg drivers :) if you were using the fglrx, the game wouldn't start :)

Comment: Actually I have the nvidia 320 drivers and you still have not provided the wine or ubuntu version.

Comment: xubuntu 3.10, latest  playonwine, i don't know what version, but latest one, my graphic cards could be found here http://askubuntu.com/questions/417826/which-graphics-divers-should-i-use and i am using `fglrx` now

Comment: i meant 13.10 :)

Comment: In my case I am using wine ditectly not pol. My version is 1.7.11

Comment: ok I'll try that, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Bugs, even more those that are well known, are off topic on the site.

Comment: Could you please tell me for next time, what questions related to Wine are accepted? Like a guideline